# Why is my network SSID shown twice?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ssid

Sometimes when I turn on my computer and open the WiFi settings, I can see my network SSID shown twice, e.g. Network1 and Network1. The second instance disappears when I reopen the WiFi settings and everything looks normal. My OS is OSX Yosemite.

Is this a problem and if so is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in OSX Yosemite's WiFi settings. It is nothing to be concerned about and can be ignored. As far as fixing it, unless you can build and compile your drivers, then you're going to have to live with this one.